# Why this scheme code can't resolve the first one of spoj?

Tags: scheme

The problem is here: http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/

And my scheme solution is:

```
(define (main) 
  (let ((line (read-line)))
    (if (or 
          (eof-object? line)
          (string=? line "42"))
        (void)
        (begin
          (display line)
          (newline)
          (main)))))

(main)
```

It reports

> runtime error (NZEC)

But I don't know why it's wrong.

Comment: You fogot to supply `read-display` (I guess it calls `main` again or something)

Comment: @Sylwester, thank you, fixed. But got the same error still

Answer (score 1):

You should install guile and try your code before you submit. Guile doesn't have `read-line` available by default. You need to add this as first line:

```
(use-modules (ice-9 rdelim))
```

So what happens is that guile post an error and return a non zero value back to the parent process, which in turns indicated the program did not terminate normally. SPOJ will then report is as NZEC.

The guile error looks like this:

```
sylwester@sylhp ~> guile test.scm
ERROR: Unbound variable: read-line
```

Whenever you get NZEC you should try to run it locally to find errors.

Comment: Thank you. I use drRacket in my local machine. I'm new to scheme, and think they are the same :(

Comment: They are very similar if you put R5RS as language. eg `(void)` won't work in DrRacket if the language is R5RS. (you get "void: unbound identifier in module in: void") You should try running in guile too just to make sure :)